# How can you view a granted and issued patent in the new USPTO system?

Tags: uspto, patent-services, my-uspto

On Mac Monterey using Safari, once clicking on the hyperlink of the patent number then searching repeated (of course) on the patent by the same number that you just clicked on, the site will be blocked to start a "pop-up windows". If you permit it, a new window will start with no content displayed therein and a new hyperlink showing to be loading or loaded. Then yet another "pop-up window", permit, pops new window, and there is this weird desktop app looking monstrosity also showing nothing.

How can you view the patent?

Comment: What site are you referring to? Does the same thing happen if you use Chrome?

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine with Google. You just need to use Google. My.uspto.gov. or google's.uspto.gov.

Comment: Why not get it via google patents ?

Comment: Because it's a government function you are paying for by all the fees you pay, maybe? And if the federal government outsources the duty of taking care of it, that's all well and good, just own up to it. When they don't, that typically only happens when money goes under the table. It is not openly claimed that Chrome is the choice because there was no open tendering of the government contract, it was probably chosen for someone having gotten money for it. I paid for the service, and won't pay for it with my data twice. And, before anything else: Google takes weeks to display an issued patent.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It's a blatant state sponsored monopoly of otherwise inferior services. (And now you can punish me for my political opinion made in the comment section by downvoting the question since you can't downvote the comment itself.)

Comment: Good question  - I was not aware of this odd behavior. I’m not sure what the SE policy is on rants in comments that accuse unidentified people of corruption. Probably allowed but discouraged.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite You asked me a question, and I answered: The above was my reason not to. I'm sure SE also discouragement into the motives of the questions when that is unnecessary to answering the question. I'm glad to discourse nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through the Patent Center; however, you can access the old interface which used to be accessible through Public Pair via https://patft.uspto.gov/ and view the patent there. In the quick version enter the patent number or other unique identifier. Chose “image” and then “full document”. The USPTO provides this (very) simple web site for free with 100% coverage and no delay in being available after issue.

Comment: This site structure that shows up after quich search, I'm sure you remember, was the same site that used to show the patent itself through Public Pair. And there you could view the .pdf and download it. It's good silver lining that it can still be accessed if you know about it's stand-alone existence. After several grants, and years of experience in U.S. patent matters, this is the first time I see the main page under https://patft.uspto.gov/ . Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

**Nohow.**

The new USPTO system no longer shows the patent in the documents view only every other correspondence, but. The image version of the patent can only be downloaded once the patent is viewed through those two pop-up windows and the specific selection is made for the viewing of the .pdf document of the patent. This can only be viewed on Google Chrome on macOS Monterey or Big Sur (neither Safari, nor Firefox will work) or else you can also choose Google to help out with Google Advanced Search. If you don't prefer the use of a Google system, then you can cough up the 50 something bucks for a certified copy although then you will have to scan it, and it won't be the actual original document itself which is a digital .pdf copy.

Comment: I can confirm this is true also on MacOS Big Sur on patentcenter.uspto.gov. It seems Chrome is required. Another good reason to use Lens.org where possible.

Comment: One can use https://patft.uspto.gov/ to bring up the image of any granted patent in any browser with a few keystrokes.